# How programically make json to have date to tabulatory react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, javascript-objects

My idea is quite complex, because I want to create something similar to `{ id: 1, Rok: 1, Cena: chart1, cena2: chart2 },` to have date to use in tabulator. I thought that I can create by loop for. I take props from parent, which want to use as a date.

```
function Table ({chart1, chart2}){
    const Data = [index, rok, data1, data2 ]
    const data1 = [];
    const data2 = [];
    const index = [];
    const rok = [];

    for(i  = 0; i< 25; i++) {
data1.push(chart1[i]);
data2.push(chart2[i]);
rok.push(`rok + ${i}`);
index.push(i);
    }
```

but the result of the operation will be look like

```
[ [1,2,3,4,5,6..], [rok1, rok2, rok3....], [], []  ]
```

then I thought about something differ, but do not work as well:

```
function Table ({chart1, chart2}){
    const Data = [];
    for(i=0; i<25; i++){
    Data.push(
    `{`"rok": + "rok" i + "id:" + i + "cena1:" + chart1[I] + "cena2": chart2[I]`}` );
    }
()}
```

Comment: could you give some portion of the original data you have, and how this data should look like at the end? i know you already gave an example, but I still don't understand.

Comment: chart1 and chart2 are  arrays that contains numbers 25each.I want them somehow put in to table to better visualisation. I have chart, now want to have table also.